# Are the $L^p$ norms ordered by $p$?

Tags: integration, lp-spaces, average

A question left over from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642939/what-does-the-lp-norm-tend-to-as-p-to-0/642940#642940) is:

Are the $L^p$ norms ordered by $p$ like the power means are?

Comment: Depends on interpretation. The ordering of *norms*  can be understood as $\|f\|_p\le \|f\|_q$ for $p\le q$. This requires $\int_\Omega dx\le 1$. If understood in the weaker sense $\|f\|_p\le C_{p,q}\|f\|_q$ for $p\le q$, then as in mookid's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\int_\Omega  dx = 1$, then the Hölder inequality states that yes.

If $\int_\Omega  dx <\infty$, then the Hölder inequality states that there is domination between the norms.

Otherwise, no ([more details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space)).